# How to check if value is selected from dropdown box or not ??

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down box as shown below

```
<select name="" id="BsnessType">
<option> Business Type</option>
<option value="101">Theatre</option>
<option value="102">Restaurant</option>
</select>
```

When clicked on submit Button when nothing is selected from the drop down 
I dont want to continue it further for the user to do operation

I have done this way

```
var businestypecode = $('#BsnessType').val();
alert(businestypecode);
if(businestypeinText =='Business Type')
{
    alert('Please select Appropiate Business Type');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I have done this way  , but it is never going to the if condition

could anybody please let me know how to check this .

Comment: If you want to check text content, you should use `text()` method over the selector `$( "#BsnessType option:selected" ).text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, problem seems to be  extra space,

```
<option> Business Type</option>
        ^
```

You may try using `selectedIndex`:

```
if(0 === $('#BsnessType').prop('selectedIndex'))//first option is selected
{
    alert('Please select Appropiate Business Type');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for your [Query- jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFtBD/2/):

```
<label class="paylabel" for="cardtype">Card Type:</label>
<select id="cardtype" name="cards">
<option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
<option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
<option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
<option value="solo">Solo (UK only)</option>
<option value="visaelectron">Visa Electron</option>
<option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click here">
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
var businestypecode = $('#BsnessType').val();
alert(businestypecode);
if(businestypeinText == '')
{
    alert('Please select Appropiate Business Type');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

You haven't set a value for your first option.

Answer (score -1):

replace,

```
 <option> Business Type</option>
```

with,

```
<option value="Business Type"> Business Type</option>
```

and,

```
if(businestypeinText =='Business Type')
{
```

with,

```
if(businestypecode =='Business Type')
{
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name="" id="BsnessType">
<option value="0"> Business Type</option>
<option value="101">Theatre</option>
<option value="102">Restaurant</option>
</select>
```

Add value too first option, for example "0" because if values are keys in database or sth (primary AI they are never less then 1!)

```
var selectVal = $('#BsnessType').val();
if(selectVal == 0){
  alert('Please select Appropiate Business Type');
}
```

Then if value == 0, alert something, hope this helps!